# Sonarqube code coverage is 0% though scan was successful in Github Action for php app

Tags: sonarqube, github-actions, php-code-coverage

I have a github action which runs the php unit test followed by Sonarqube scanner but the Sonarqube code coveage is always 0%

Phpunit Test is ok
Sonaiqube ok as well but no CodeCoverage

**These is my Github action script eliminated some jobs related to unitest in here :**

```
name: front-data-stage-unittest
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        php: ['8.1']
    name: PHP ${{ matrix.php }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository and submodules
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: recursive
          token: ${{ secrets.SUBMODULE_TOKEN }}
      - name: Install PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@master
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php }}
          extensions: mbstring, dom, fileinfo, mysql
          coverage: xdebug

      - uses: php-actions/composer@v5
        with:
          php_version: 8.1
          args: --profile --ignore-platform-reqs --optimize-autoloader

      - name: Execute PHPUnit tests
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-clover=coverage.xml

      - name: SonarQube Scan
        uses: SonarSource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        with:
          args: >
            -Dsonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
```

**sonar-project.properties:**

```
sonar.projectKey=tara_app
sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml
```

**Possible cause:**
looking at the logs looks like its not finding the file but anyone worked on generating or making it work via github action

```
14:06:11.466 INFO: 1157/1193 files analyzed, current file: app/Http/Controllers/V2/PerformanceController.php
14:06:13.823 INFO: 1193/1193 source files have been analyzed
14:06:13.825 WARN: PHPUnit xml test report not found: tests/report/test.xml
14:06:13.826 INFO: No PHPUnit coverage reports provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths' property)
14:06:13.826 INFO: Sensor PHP sensor [php] (done) | time=88263ms
14:06:13.826 INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
```

Comment: Do you have a `.properties` file as well?

Comment: From the logs, it looks like you need to set `sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml`. See [Usage](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-scan-action#usage) and https://docs.sonarcloud.io/enriching/test-coverage/php-test-coverage/ for more details.

Comment: I have the `sonar-project.properties` added with `sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.xml` added as well that is not helping @Azeem

Comment: Right. Please add that to your question also. Also, there's a warning in the logs that the report is not found. Were you able to track it down?

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem is not preserved between jobs. Thus your reports generated from your `Test` jobs are not available to your `run-sonarqube`  job.

If you want to share files between jobs you need to use [artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts).

After your phpunit step add a step using `actions/upload-artifact` and then add a step before your scan using `actions/download-artifact` to pull the report into that job.

Comment: Basically, this are the changes I did
1. Made unit test to output coverage report as well `run: vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-xml coverage-reports/coverage.xml`
2. added the `actions/upload-artifact` to upload the coverage.xml verified as well its ok
3. Similarly download as well to sonarqube scanner job but still the same

Comment: I tried adding it to same jobs as well instead of running it separately so no need of upload/download but not able to find the exact cause